# C#: How do I wait 10 seconds for a client to call a method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, signalr, signalr-hub

On a server(Web API), I have methods A and B. When method A reaches a certain point it uses SignalR to call a client method with a certain ID and then has to wait 10 seconds. If a client calls web method B with that ID within those 10 seconds then method A enters Path 1. If a client does not call method B then method A enters Path 2. Do you have any ideas on how to implement that?
Thank you,
Peter Chikov

Comment: This is awfully vague.  Which part of this are you having a hard time with?

Comment: The part where I have to wait for the client to call Method B (how do I write this code) and then stop waiting after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is designed to be stateless.  If possible, the server should not be attempting to keep track of the client's state.  Can you change your implementation so that the client initiates a new request after the SignalR call and then enters path #1 or #2?

Comment: Might have to do it that way, however it will be inefficient. Please see my comment above. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Is there any reason not to implement the wait on the client-side?  (1) SignalR server -> client (2) client waits 10s (3) client calls webmethod B with an indication of whether or not the user interacted within the 10s window